# Unable to insert into Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert data using this SQL statement into an Oracle table but I am getting missing right parenthesis error:

```
insert into new_table T (T."DATE", T.SERVER, T.value1, T.value2) 
VALUES (to_date(2014-05-20-16.29.45, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS'), 'serverA', 11.325, 203.30)
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
insert into new_table T (T."DATE", T.SERVER, T.value1, T.value2) 
VALUES (to_date('2014-05-20-16.29.45', 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS'), 'serverA', 11.325, 203.30)
```

You were missing quotes around your date string.

By the way, it's usually not a good idea to name a column `date`.Not only is it a reserved word, but what if you add another date column to your table? Better to rename it something like `modified_date` or `order_date`.